# How to call name space with id given on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, onload

How to call name space with id given on page load

i have following name space

```
      var panel = panel || {};

        panel = (function() {
            var div_pass = function (id) {
                id_given=id;

            };
            var type = function(type_pass) {

                type_given=type_pass;

            };

            return {


                divid : function() {

                    return type_given;
                 }


            };

        }());
```

i am calling this on page load as

```
onload="panel.div_pass('window')"
```

this do not calling div_pass i put alert but showing in div_pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call `panel.div_pass` then you need to return div_pass on panel.

```
return {
  divid : function() {
    return type_given;
  },
  div_pass: div_pass
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var panel = panel || {};
panel =  {
     divid : function() {
         return type_given;
     },
      div_pass:function(id){
          alert(id)
      }
};
```